# How do I pick out values between a duplicate value in a collection?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a method that returns a collection that has a duplicate value.

```
static List<string> GenerateItems()
{
    var _items = new List<string>();
    _items.Add("Tase");
    _items.Add("Ray");
    _items.Add("Jay");
    _items.Add("Bay");
    _items.Add("Tase");
    _items.Add("Man");
    _items.Add("Ran");
    _items.Add("Ban");

    return _items;
}
```

I want to search through that collection and find the first place that duplicate value is located and start collecting all the values from the first appearance of the duplicate value to its next appearance. I want to put this in a collection but I only want the duplicate value to appear once in that collection.

This is what I have so far but.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string key = "Tase";
    var collection = GenerateItems();
    int index = collection.FindIndex(a => a == key);

    var matchFound = false;
    var itemsBetweenKey = new List<string>();

    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        if (item == key)
        {
            matchFound = !matchFound;
        }
        if (matchFound)
        {
            itemsBetweenKey.Add(item);
        }
    }
    foreach (var item in itemsBetweenKey)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

There must be an easier way of doing this. Perhaps with Indexing or a LINQ query?

Comment: What is the issue with the code you posted?

Comment: Feels like you have a different task but you changed the question to not show what you actually need but still get an answer. This makes it very difficult to understand what you want

Comment: List<string>  comes with an .IndexOf("yourString", occurranceCount) method you can use to get your start and end indexes and then .GetRange(startIndex, (EndIndex - StartIndex))

Comment: Can you get duplicates between a duplicate? If this is the case your code wont work. i.e. 

 - Tase
 - Apple
 - {some normal keys},
 - Apple
 - {more normal keys}
 - Tase

In this case do you want two lists as the output?
List1 - Tase, Apple, {some normal keys}, {more normal keys}
List2- Apple, , {some normal keys}

Or some other output?

If this is the case you might want to look at using a recursive method.

Comment: just for clarrification: you have always exactly 1 duplicate in the entire collection? and you even know its value in advance?

Comment: _items.Add("Tase");
    _items.Add("Ray");
    _items.Add("Jay");
    _items.Add("Bay");
    _items.Add("Tase");
    _items.Add("Man");
    _items.Add("Ran");
    _items.Add("Ban");
from those, what should the code return ?

Comment: `var result = collection.SkipWhile(x=>x!=key).TakeWhile(x=>x!=key);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that

```
string key = "Tase";
var collection = GenerateItems();
int indexStart = collection.FindIndex(a => a == key);
int indexEnd = collection.FindIndex(indexStart+1, a => a == key);

var result = collection.GetRange(indexStart, indexEnd-indexStart);
```

Comment: Think this is what OP wanted. Good answer. For a similar problem where there can be more then 2 duplicates in the sequence this will not work.

Comment: like so? https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZZc1Lt

Comment: OP mentioned he wanted the value in question to also be in the list so your '-1' should not be there

Comment: ow missed that :)

Comment: I have editted not sure, its visible or i should reshare

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq select and group by to find the first index and last index of all duplicates (Keep in mind if something is in the list more then 2 times it would ignore the middle occurences.

But I personally think the linq for this seems overcomplicated. I would stick with simple for loops and if statements (Just turn it into a method so it reads better)

Here is a solution with Linq to get all duplicate and all values between those duplicates including itself once as you mentioned.

```
var collection = GenerateItems();
var Duplicates = collection.Select((x,index) => new { index, value = x })
                           .GroupBy(x => x.value)//group by the strings
                           .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)//only take duplicates
                           .Select(x=>new {
                                       Value = x.Key, 
                                       FirstIndex = x.Min(y=> y.index),//take first occurenc
                                       LastIndex = x.Max(y => y.index)//take last occurence
                           }).ToList();

var resultlist = new List<List<string>>();

foreach (var duplicaterange in Duplicates)
            resultlist .Add(collection.GetRange(duplicaterange.FirstIndex, duplicaterange.LastIndex - duplicaterange.FirstIndex));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
public List<string> PickOut(List<string> collection, string key)
{
    var index = 0;
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        if (item == key)
        {
            return collection.Skip(index).TakeWhile(x=> x != key).ToList();
        }
        index++;
    };
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First finding the duplicate key then find the second occurrence of the item and then take result.

```
var firstduplicate = collection.GroupBy(x => x)
                    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                    .Select(g => g.Key).First();

var indices = collection.Select((b, i) => b == firstduplicate ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
if (indices>0) 
{
    var result = collection.Take(indices).ToList();
}
```